# Custom AlertDialog with ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm dealing with Menu -> SubMenus navigation and I'm facing an issue.

My first screen is a ListView that takes all the screen, what I would like is that when a ListItem is selected, it goes to another activity but with an AlertDialog composed of a ListView that takes half the screen in height. So when the user taps away the dialog box, it disapears.

So I know how to set a Listener on the first ListView, jump to another Activity passing the data from the item selected in order to get the Dialog's ListView populated with an AsyncTask but I don't know how to get this AlertDialog composed of a ListView

Could anyone help me please?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use custom dialog like this

```
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        dialog.setTitle("Title...");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
```

**Note** In R.layout.custom insert a listview